# Error pulling image (latest) from centos, Authentication is required

Tags: linux, centos, containers, docker, lxc

I have installed docker.io on CentOS 6.4 64 bit following the steps mentioned here: http://nareshv.blogspot.in/2013/08/installing-dockerio-on-centos-64-64-bit.html

Now I am able to start the docker daemon. When I am searching for a container as follows it's giving me result

```
 [root@test ~]# docker search tutorial

 Found 8 results matching your query ("tutorial")
 NAME                             DESCRIPTION
 mhubig/echo                      Simple echo loop from the tutorial.
 learn/tutorial
 jbarbier/tutorial1
 mzdaniel/buildbot-tutorial
 kyma/ping                        Ping image from the tutorial.
 ivarvong/redis                   From the redis tutorial. Just redis-server and       telnet on the base image.
 amattn/postgresql-9.3.0          precise base, PostgreSQL 9.3.0 installed w/ default   configuration.  http://amattn.com/2013/09/19/tutorial_postgresql_us...
```

danlucraft/postgresql            Postgresql 9.3, on port 5432, un:docker, pw:docker. From  following the Postgresql example tutorial.

But When I am trying to pull a container it's giving me below error

```
[root@test ~]# docker pull learn/tutorial
Pulling repository learn/tutorial
8dbd9e392a96: Error pulling image (latest) from learn/tutorial, Authentication is required.
2013/10/08 02:50:01 Internal server error: 404 trying to fetch remote history for learn/tutorial
```

How to set the authentication and where? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and [this answer](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1867#issuecomment-26366290) was the solution for me.

It was a time-zone issue. I ran docker on a VM, and my host and guest clock had different ctimezone, the authentication failure was due to clock divergence. Once I setup ntp correctly (with HW clock set to UTC) on my host, this problem went away.